# How to fix tableview from loading cells in the same row?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am setting up tableview programmatically, I am constructing a setting page with sections, but for some reason my cells loads on the same row, maybe there is something easy I am missing, I need help to fix this problem here is a snapshot for what I am getting.

My intent to create a static custom cells, I had initially structured custom cells to load without the dequeueReusableCell use, but it loaded the cells again on the same row, I tried using array of cells configure each row with switch cases and had the similar result, and I ended up going with very simple array of strings and configure cells within cellForRowAt but also it didn't work.

```swift
import UIKit
class SettingsVC: UIViewController, StoryboardCoordinator , UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    //MARK: - Variables
    var tableView = UITableView()
    weak var coordinator: MainCoordinator?
    let settings = ["Password Lock", "Unlock With TouchID", "Access Your Location?"]
    //MARK: - TableView UI configuration
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return settings.count
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! SettingsRow
        cell.switchView.rowTitle.text = settings[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setup()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(SettingsRow.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        tableView.allowsSelection = false
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
    func setup() {
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        addConstraints()
    }
    func addConstraints(){
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),])
    }
}
```

Comment: What does *"my cells loads on the same row"* mean? What is your actual result compared to what you expect? Your table view code looks fine.

Comment: https://imgur.com/BjdUdkP here is a photo from the app running

Comment: Unrelated but you should be calling `tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` before you call `addConstraints()`.

Comment: I usually initialize my views through closures and add stuff like that within, but I tried to fall back to the way it is written to see if that was the issue.

Comment: other than some of the setup code being a bit mixed up (as per above) there's nothing glaringly wrong, so I'd be looking at the cell initialiser/config code - can you add that to the question.

Comment: @flanker your comment guided me to the issue somehow, When you mentioned the cell code I was going to copy it over and found that I had translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints in the override init constructor, when I commented it out everything loads now perfectly.

Comment: Glad you managed to sort it.